# css for paragraph styling not working

Tags: css

I have the below code that's part of a php script. The

brackets work correctly i.e if I change it to h1 heading it shows heading 1 but when I try to use a class for style it does not. What am I doing wrong?

```
<p class="indexletters">-<a name="'.substr($row['name'],0,1).'">'.substr

($row['name'],0,1).'-</p>
```

And this is the css

```
p.indexletters { 
color:#00A383;letter-spacing:1px;font-family: PosterBodoni; font-size: 

50px; margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;"
```

Thank you

Comment: can you post the output of the PHP instead?

Comment: if I view the page source this is whats displayed from the code <p class="indexletters">-<a name="B">B-</p>

Comment: And the only other CSS I have relating to the P tag is this P  {color:#3A3A3A;letter-spacing:2px; line-height:150%;font-

family:helvetica;}

Comment: You're not closing your `<a>` tag. Add a `</a>` before the `-</p>`.

Comment: I'm an idiot, I had another look at my CSS file because the style worked if put directly into the p tag. I had somehow deleted the previous bit of stylings end bracket } I added the } and it worked perfectly. Sorry for wasting your time but thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're ending with `"` CSS should look like this:

```
p.indexletters{ 
    color:#00A383;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    font-family: PosterBodoni;
    font-size: 50px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
}
```

Comment: I noticed the erroneous ", I have deleted it but still it does not work. The " was left over from when I tested it inline <p style="CSS"> where it worked fine. I'm stumped.